# Asking too much gas fee for transaction, Returned error: theta RPC returns an error

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, remix

I have deployed my contract on theta mainnet. It was working fine for few days but now it is asking too much gas fee for transaction.
I am using web3 "v1.3.1" on server side nodejs
[image]

Comment: Can you share the contract code? Did you try with see if the gas consumption in a testnet network? Without more details it could be a bug in the contract.